# How to implement microservices correctly with Springboot?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to convert to Springboot concept by example, here is an example:
I have User class/object which include cart with JPA annotation at the current application
the cart is loaded eagerly by JPA when using the respectful query as follow:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@Unversioned
public ShoppingCart getCart() {
    return cart;
}
```

According to Springboot concept, the Cart should have its own service and own database, is this
means that the code above should be removed?
If yes, every time the fronted code (Angular in my case) request the cart I'll need to make
a call to the cart service.
Another question is, what happen when you need to use an Entity in two different services ?
In the examples I saw so far, a pojo is copied to a service but without the @Entity annotation.
This will cause problem in maintenance as I will need to update each service who hold a copy
of the pojo.
Thanks.

Comment: This is a very verbose question to ask! I will recommend you read a whole book for this. Checkout building Microservices by Sam Newman

Comment: Spring Boot is equally suited to building monoliths as it is to building microservices. If you want to learn some of the advantages and disadvantages of microservices then that’s a good thing to do, but don’t feel that you have to use microservices just because you are using Spring Boot. A monolith is often a better choice.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I understand your point, I would like to implement microservices in order to add skills to my skillset, that's why I choose to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very verbose question to ask! I will recommend you read a whole book for this.
It's a whole lot of brilliant practices and there is no permanent way of building Microservices.
Checkout "building Microservices"  by Sam Newman

Comment: I prefer to learn by examples as I always do, do you have answer, It will be helpful

Comment: There is no direct answer to your question...how would you like it if I copy and paste a whole book explaining Microservices architecture for you? Also I noticed from your question details above, it doesn't seem like you know precisely what you want! Asking how some springboot features works is independent of Microservices. Again, pls try take your time to read a book and you will understand and enjoy building services in a monolithic way. Note: springboot is not equal to Microservices, in short, you can use nodeJs, laravel lumen, .net, e.t.c... to build a Microservice.

Comment: I watched videos today on youtube and read few articles and I understand that microservice not necessary deal with 1 entity, it described as dealing with business process, such as authentication, customerdetails etc.